# Cómo agregar un punto de interés en especifico con MapBox en Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity, mapbox

Es mi primera vez utilizando MapBox en Unity.
Tengo la duda de como agregar un punto de interés en un sector específico, como lo sería una casa o un local en concreto.
Además, me gustaría que me muestre un mensaje al acercarme a este punto.
Eh estado buscando por documentación sobre el tema, pero no encuentro nada útil.
Muchas gracias por todo.